# How to use Google Chart with data from a csv

Tags: javascript, csv, google-visualization

I have a csv file that looks like that:

```
week,value1,value2
1,2,3
2,7,9
```

I would like to plot a stacked graph of it using google chart (week being my x (horizontal) values and values1 and values2 being the two set of y's). Unfortunately, I didn't find any easy way to do so. That probably relates to me being a complete noob in js.

Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [jquery-csv library](https://github.com/typeiii/jquery-csv) provides the ability to translate a string of csv into an array to be used by `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()` (their example [here](https://typeiii.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/google-visualization.html)). To make this work, add jquery.csv.js to your server (in the example below I assume it is in the same folder as your HTML) and link to it in your `<head>`. The following is a simple script you can add to your `<head>` to get started. I assume a scatter chart, but this process works for any of the charts [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery). You will also need a `<div>` with `id="chart"` for this to work.

```
// load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// this has to be a global function
function drawChart() {
   // grab the CSV
   $.get("example.csv", function(csvString) {
      // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

      // this new DataTable object holds all the data
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

      // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0,1]);

     // set chart options
     var options = {
        title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
        vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
        legend: 'none'
     };

     // create the chart object and draw it
     var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
     chart.draw(view, options);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been searching for a while, and found the solution on a Google group discussion.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/cnXYDr411tQ

I have tried it, and it works!

In this case, we have to specify the header types of our csv file.

```
var queryOptions = {
    csvColumns: ['number', 'number', 'number' /* Or whatever the columns in the CSV file are */],
    csvHasHeader: true /* This should be false if your CSV file doesn't have a header */
}
/* csvUrl is the path to your csv */    
var query = new google.visualization.Query(csvUrl, queryOptions);
query.send(handleQueryResponse);

function handleQueryResponse(response) {

    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('your div'));
    // Draw your chart with the data table here.
    // chart.draw(view, queryOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What server side scripting language are you working in (php, asp)?

One option could be to import the data from a spreadsheet saved in Google Drive, [see here](http://www.farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/) for a PHP based example of saving and extracting data from Google Docs. This would then enable you to update the spreadsheet and the chart would automatically plot the new data.

Comment: I want to do it entirely client-side (server should only serve the html file and the csv)…