# Google Motion Chart Date Format

Tags: html, csv, format, google-visualization

Im using google motion charts to graph some data from a csv file. The file looks like so

```
411,(10/4/2014),24,21
371,(10/5/2014),247,239
959,(10/6/2014),266,23
680,(10/7/2014),211,24
```

But everytime I try to get it to graph the data I get the error "First and second columns must be entity and time.". What format does the date in the file need to be in?

I modified  jlee-tessik idea and came up with the below code which successfully converts any dd/mm/yyyy to a date. Thanks

```html
     $.get(csvFile, function(csvString) {
    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
   for(i = 1; i < arrayData.length; ++i)
   {
    arrayData[i][1] = new Date (arrayData[i][1].replace(/\//g, ','));
   }
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
```

Comment: why do you dont cant do not use google chart?

Answer (score 0):

The first column needs to be a string, and the second needs to be a date, so be sure to initialize your first two columns with the right data types:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Field1');
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
```

and assuming your first column is the label you wanted:

```
data.addRows([
    ['411', new Date (2014,10,4), 24, 21],
    ['371', new Date (2014,10,5), 247, 239],
    ['959', new Date (2014,10,6), 266, 23],
    ['680', new Date (2014,10,7), 211, 24]
]);
```

EDIT: I didn't understand your question at first. jquery-csv doesn't seem to support date parsing with its basic parse, but you can add a custom hook to format your data specifically the way you want. Here with the first row, I'm grabbing column 2, stripping out the parenthesis, and converting it to a date.

```
var col2date = function(value, state) {
    if(state.colNum == 2) {
        return new Date (value.replace(/[{()} ]/g, ''));
    }
    return value;
}

var dataRows = $.csv.toArrays("411,(10/4/2014),24,21", { onParseValue: col2date });
```

Comment: That wont work because that "new Date  (dd/mm/yyyy)" is hard coded, mine is coming in from a csv file where the new Date command is not recongnized

Comment: Then you'll probably need to convert your csv coming in, see jquery-csv library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211636/how-to-use-google-chart-with-data-from-a-csv.

Comment: I already am using jquery-csv to read the file, but google charts doesnt recognize dates with days and months coming in from a file

Comment: Please look at my edit above to see how jquery-csv can be used to parse your data.