# Chart.js / Google Charts and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, charts, chart.js

I am trying to create a dashboard from a csv string using google charts and chart.js. I need to modify and add to the dataset; things like category totals, averages, and team (grouped) totals and averages.

What would be the most efficient approach with the least amount of code? Should I convert the string to an array of objects, then work with that?

Also, how do I create charts in google charts and chart.js with json data?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the most efficient approach with the least amount of
>   code? Should I convert the string to an array of objects, then work
>   with that?

Converting the string to a format required by Chart.js would be a necessary step. Chart.js does not accept csv as an input. The appropriate format varies by chart type (line, pie...)

For Google charts - see [How to use Google Chart with data from a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211636/how-to-use-google-chart-with-data-from-a-csv)

---

> Also, how do I create charts in google charts and chart.js with json
>   data?

For Chart.js, the documentation (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-introduction) has examples for each chart type to get you started.

The same for Google charts - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start